# Wordpress construction worksite induction solution

Tags: wordpress, lms

I'm considering the creation of an in-house construction site induction (or onboarding, I suppose) solution using Wordpress. This would detail the site location (with maps), the site rules and any other relevent information that people working on the site (or visitors) need. Immediate thought is to use an LMS (learning management system) plugin where each 'course' would be a different construction site. Has anybody done something similar and have recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar to this but it would work much better in a multi-site environment. Utilizing an LMS as the solution for this could get complicated in the long run and need some coding changes to work effectively.

Through Multi-Site, you could have a member platform that allows the user to see the relevant information after logging in. Also keeps things more clean and separate on the admin side of things.

Comment: I did consider MultiSite but have never used it before. It's more the moving through the 'lessons' (or pages, I suppose) in a set order.